# How can i identify the generated Object from the Hibernate Query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, struts

I am trying to fetch the records from the mysql database with the hibernate framework. To achieve this i had written the below code.

```
 List addresses = session.createQuery("Select P.address,P.personal_email,P.contact FROM PermanentAddress P,Employee E WHERE E.login_account='"+inf.getlogin_account()+"' AND E.employee_no=P.empno").list();
 for (Iterator iterator = addresses.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
     PermanentAddress pa= (PermanentAddress) iterator.next();
     ad.setpaddr(pa.getaddress());
     ad.setpemail(pa.getpersonal_email());
     ad.setpcontact(pa.getcontact());
     System.out.println(ad.getpemail());
 }
```

when i ran this code i am getting the below error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.lms.model.PermanentAddress
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:545)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:486)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

please show me the way.

Comment: Please provide mapping file of `PermanentAddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are returning a list of fields (`P.address,P.personal_email,P.contact`) from `PermanentAddress`, instead of the whole entities. Try something like this:

```
 List addresses = session.createQuery("Select P FROM PermanentAddress P,Employee E WHERE E.login_account = '" + inf.getlogin_account() + "' AND E.employee_no=P.empno").list();
```